# How to group a data.table by a column supplied as string?

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the `data.table` package to speed up some summary statistic collection on a data set.

I'm curious if there's a way to group by more than one column. My data looks like this:

```
Date             Cluster         Value  
2016-12-11          A              36
2016-12-11          B              40
2016-12-11          C              17
2016-12-12          A              41
2016-12-12          B              27
2016-12-12          C              19
...
2017-2-21           A              22
2017-2-21           B              35
2017-2-21           C              27
```

I wanna get the data like this:

```
Date             Cluster         Value       Total
2016-12-11          A              36          93
2016-12-11          B              40          93
2016-12-11          C              17          93
2016-12-12          A              41          87
2016-12-12          B              27          87
2016-12-12          C              19          87
...
2017-2-21           A              22          84
2017-2-21           B              35          84
2017-2-21           C              27          84
```

My Code:

```
colName <- "Cluster"

dt[, list(colName, Value, Total=sum(Value)), by = c("Date")]
```

I can only get the data like this:

```
Date             colName         Value       Total
2016-12-11       Cluster           36          93
2016-12-11       Cluster           40          93
2016-12-11       Cluster           17          93
2016-12-12       Cluster           41          87
2016-12-12       Cluster           27          87
2016-12-12       Cluster           19          87
...
2017-2-21        Cluster           22          84
2017-2-21        Cluster           35          84
2017-2-21        Cluster           27          84
```

The `colName` is an argument from input. That's the problem.

Comment: The accepted answer is better but for reference if you want to pass strings you can use `eval(substitute ("str"))` in dt scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you just want to add a Total (grouped by Date), you can add a Total column using the `data.table` `:=` operator (will keep all existing columns):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- structure(list(Date = c("2016-12-11", "2016-12-11", "2016-12-11", 
  "2016-12-12", "2016-12-12", "2016-12-12", "2017-02-21", "2017-02-21", 
  "2017-02-21"), Cluster = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
  "B", "C"), Value = c(36L, 40L, 17L, 41L, 27L, 19L, 22L, 35L, 
  27L)), .Names = c("Date", "Cluster", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -9L), class = "data.frame")
setDT(dt)
dt[, ":="(Total=sum(Value, na.rm = TRUE)), by = Date]
```

This produces a data.table `dt` with `Total` being the `sum` of `Value` (per `Date`) and includes the `Cluster` column:

```
         Date Cluster Value Total
1: 2016-12-11       A    36    93
2: 2016-12-11       B    40    93
3: 2016-12-11       C    17    93
4: 2016-12-12       A    41    87
5: 2016-12-12       B    27    87
6: 2016-12-12       C    19    87
7: 2017-02-21       A    22    84
8: 2017-02-21       B    35    84
9: 2017-02-21       C    27    84
```

**EDIT:** `data.table` syntax allows to write the statement with a little less typing as well as

```
dt[, Total := sum(Value, na.rm = TRUE), by = Date]
```